# Re-render all components in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, react-redux

I have simple app:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import { setLanguage, currentLanguage, availableLanguages } from '../localization';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as appActions from '../actions/appActions';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
  }
  setLanguageHandle(twoLetter, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLanguage(twoLetter);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul id='languageDropdown' className='dropdown-content'>
          {availableLanguages().map((item, i) =>
            <li key={i}><a href='' onClick={this.setLanguageHandle.bind(this, item.twoLetterISOLanguageName)}>{item.nativeName}</a></li>
            )}
        </ul>
        <nav className='cyan'>
          <div className='nav-wrapper'>
            <a className='brand-logo' style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}>SUPP</a>
            <ul className='right hide-on-med-and-down'>
              <li>
                <a className='dropdown-button' href='' data-activates='languageDropdown'>
                  {currentLanguage().nativeName}
                  <i className='material-icons right'>arrow_drop_down</i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className='container'>
          <MainPage />
        </div>
        <footer className='page-footer cyan'>
          <div className='footer-copyright'>
            <div className='container'>
              <span style={{ fontWeight: 'normal' }}>© 2017</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps() {
  return {
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    appActions: bindActionCreators(appActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Here i have simple localization dropdown, where I'm clicking on language, then it fires `setLanguageHandle`. `setLanguage` from `../localization` uses cookie to set language.

`MainPage` component and it's children load all their properties from Redux. Localization is the only exception and looks like `_localize('sometext')`, which uses:

```js
export function _(key) {
    let currentCulture = getCurrentCultureFromCookie();
    let translation = translations[currentCulture]['translations'][key];
    return translation;
}
```

so, no Redux  is used in localization.

The problem is, that when I'm changing the culture, children components don't re-rendering. I tried to call my synthetic Redux action, which changes one independent variable in store, but nothing re-rendering, seems it's too smart for doing such kind of job.

How can I re-render all my components in whole application, when I call `setLanguageHandler` to supply on-fly culture switching? Maybe there's another way for such things, to do it without reloading the whole page?

Comment: Have you tried [forceUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen yes, it only updates App component, it doesn't affect App's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use redux for localization. Specifically, I think you should put "currentCulture" into your store. Then replace the calls to your "_localize" method with a Localize component that might look something like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function Localize(props) {
    return (
        <span>{translations[props.currentCulture]['translations'][props.textKey]}</span>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {currentCulture: state.currentCulture};
};
const LocalizeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Localize);
export default LocalizeContainer;
```

Which you could then use with something like:

```
<Localize textKey="sometext" />
```

I realize this is a significant change in approach, but I think you're asking for headaches by having parts of your rendering that are controlled by a variable that is not in your state.

An alternative/complementary approach that can be used more flexibly (such as in property values) would be a container that injects a "localize" method as a property of the wrapped component.

In a "localize.js":

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const localizeText = currentCulture => textKey => { return translations[currentCulture]['translations'][textKey]; };

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { localize: localizeText(state.currentCulture) };
};

export default function localize(LocalizedComponent) {
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(LocalizedComponent);
}
```

Then to use it:

```
import React from "react";
import localize from "./localize.js"

function YourDisplayComponent(props) {
    return (
        <input value={props.localize(props.inputValueKey)}>
    );
}
export default localize(YourDisplayComponent);
```

Comment: Seems good, but what should we do, if we want to localize something like `<input value='i need to localize this value' placeholder='i need to localize this too'>`?

Comment: I've added to my answer an alternative approach that addresses the use case of needing to localize property values.

Comment: As far as I understand, with second method, we just need to wrap component where we want to use localization in `localize` function? How should we wrap already wrapped components, e. g. `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)`?

Comment: It should work fine to just doubly wrap it, e.g.  `export default localize(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));`

Comment: No, it doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _localization.localize) is not a function`. This is the only thing which left to achieve the perfect localization.

Comment: Please show an example of how you're trying to use the localize method within the doubly-wrapped component.

Comment: absolutely like you proposed: `{this.props.localize('my key')}`, but it doesn't matter, because error in this line: `export default localize(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));`.

Comment: This works fine for me. Have you successfully tried this out in a component that is not wrapped?

Comment: Yes, with component which isn't wrapped, it works. Could you provide example how it works in your case?

Comment: Ok, in this case i works, what about using classes intead of functions?

Comment: Here's a fiddle using classes: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmprbbub/5/)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!